# Where to start developing a business project( UI / Server / Database)

Tags: workflow

I need advice about project workflow,
From the characterization where to go?
Today it's my workflow :

- Characterization
- UI (FrontEnd)(Angular / React / Vue etc.)
- UI (BackEnd)(Angular / React / Vue etc.)
- Server(.NET API / Node.js etc.)
- Database(SQL Server / Mongo / MySql etc.)

sorry if this is not a correct place for the question.thank for answers.

Comment: Actually, there is no right or wrong whether you start with the backend or the frontend. That’s all about personal preference and what makes you feel more comfortable on the way to your final goal. But you should keep in mind that a missing backend requires service mocking in the frontend, which might slow your progress down a little.

Comment: first, thank you for the fast answer, and another question, what a more flexible method?

Comment: The first thing you should put a lot of effort in is to analyze what your data model is supposed to look like. What are the business objects' structures you need to cover your aim. Having this I personally would start developing the frontend, even though this means mocking. But I made the experience that the frontend changes very quickly during the development and with it the backend requirements. And it's easier to adapt the backend to the frontend, from my perspective.